# Redirect/render modal with ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have one rails application in which I need to check if the user is not authenticated while using a particular page then it should show login modal on the same page and background should be faded.

For that, I have one method called `authenticate user` in the application controller

```
def authenticated_user
 if user
 else
  # from here I want to open a sign in modal
 end
end
```

My current `sessions/new` method is following,

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I also have new.js.erb in sessions folder in views,

```
$("#modal-window").find(".modal-content").html("<%= escape_javascript( render 'sessions/new', formats: [ :html ]) %>");
$("#modal-window").modal();
```

I have tried sending ajax request with following,

```
redirect_to sessions_path(format: :js)
```

but it instead redirects me too `http://localhost:3000/reader/login.js` rather than opening modal on the same page.

Comment: From my previous experience, you cannot use redirect_to sessions_path(format: :js) to achieve this. And may I ask that the request to authenticate_user is ajax or html?

Comment: authenticate_user is method which I call in before filter of any request(In my case it's html requests only).

Answer (score 0):

From my previous experience, this cannot be achieved through `redirect_to sessions_path(format: :js)`

You could try the following:

For before_action

```
def authenticated_user
  if user
  else
    if request.xhr?
      render :authenticated_user and return
    else
      redirect_to request.env['HTTP_REFERER'], flash: { authenticated_user: true }
    end
  end
end
```

In layout file:

```
...
- if flash[:authenticated_user]
  <%= render 'authenticated_user_modal' %>
...
```

authenticated_user.js.erb

```
<% html = capture do %>
  <%= render 'authenticated_user_modal' %>
<% end %>

$('body').append('<%=j html %>');
$('#modal-window').modal();
# add a method that remove the modal after close it.
# $(document).on('close-modal', '#modal-window', function () {
#   $('#modal-window').remove();
# });
```

_authenticated_user_modal.html.erb

```
<div id="modal-window">
  ...
</div>

:javascript
  $('#modal-window').modal();
```